Understanding behavior of super() in subclassing Object vs. custom wrapper function
Subclassing Object and using super()
class C extends Object {
      constructor(v) {
        super(v);
      }
    }
    
    console.log(new C(1) instanceof Number); // false

Custom Wrapper Function:
function MyObject(v) {
  return new Object(v);
}

class D extends MyObject {
  constructor(v) {
    super(v);
  }
}

console.log(new D(1) instanceof Number); // true

I know MDN docs mention this that in directly subclassing Object it ignores arguments but I'm still not able to understand it fully like why does it do so? What exactly is happening behind the scenes when super(v) is used in a subclass extending Object, and how does it differ from using a wrapper function that explicitly returns an object?

Where do you have a subclass extending Object?

@Pointy class C extends Object

Oh OK durr. Well, the Object constructor does not ignore an argument. —wait, now I see what you're talking about.

What's your question? Why the first code prints false or why the second code prints true?

Yes @jabaa that is the question

That are two questions. Please ask one question per question. Which one is it?

Well if you read that link in my confused comment above, the MDN docs explicitly use your example. The constructor (Object()) knows that what's being constructed is a C instance, not an Object instance, so it doesn't perform the object "promotion" that it normally would for a primitive value.

Pointy answered your first question.
Answer to your second question ("how does it differ from using a wrapper function that explicitly returns an object?"):
If A is a function that returns an object, like
function A() {
  return new Date();
}

then new A() (or, equivalently, A()) is the returned object, and not necessarily an instance of A:
a = new A(), console.log(a instanceof A,
                         a instanceof Date)
// false true

The same is true for a subclass of A:
class B extends A {}
b = new B(), console.log(b instanceof B,
                         b instanceof A,
                         b instanceof Date)
// false false true

That's why, in your case, new D(1) is [Number: 1] and
d = new D(1), console.log(d instanceof D,
                          d instanceof MyObject,
                          d instanceof Number)
// false false true

